# Cant generate *.bundle.js files after upgrading to Angular 7

Tags: angular, upgrade, angular7

I upgraded to Angular 7 and now my code won't generate the production files?

I used to run the command: npm run dist

which would generate the below files:

- inline.bundle.js
- polyfills.bundle.js
- styles.bundle.js
- vendor.bundle.js
- main.bundle.js

In my package.json file I have:

```
  "name": "angular-master",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --port 8080",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "copy": "xcopy \"dist\" \"..\\webapp\\Scripts\\ng-app\" /i /s /r /y /c",
    "dist": "npm run build && npm run copy"
```

},

Note the "copy" and "dist" - this is supposed to take the files from the dist folder and place them in my folder for production...

my tsconfig.app.json:

```
  {
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    //"baseUrl": "src",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
   },
   "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
 }
```

and my tsconfig.json file:

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
"sourceMap": true,
"declaration": false,
"moduleResolution": "node",
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"allowJs": true,
"target": "es5",
"typeRoots": [
  "node_modules/@types"
],
"lib": [
  "es2017",
  "dom"
],
"module": "es2015",
"baseUrl": "./"
//"baseUrl": "src"
}
}
```